# Referencing the type definitions for Vue.js in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to get type checking in my Vue.js code (v2.2.1). As a start I just want this one line to compile with TypeScript (i.e., I want the Vue class to be recognized):

```
var app = new Vue();
```

This compiles if I import Vue with:

```
import * as Vue from 'vue';
```

However, it generates a `require()` call:

```
var Vue = require("vue");
```

I do not use modules, I simply reference the Vue library from a CDN before my script.

I tried referencing the definition file as so:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/vue/types/index.d.ts" />
```

But the Vue class is not recognized (presumably because it is exported in the definition file and hence should be imported?).

Can I use `import` to only reference the type definitions without 'requiring' the the library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own definition file (e.g. *vue-global.d.ts*) where `Vue` will be defined in global namespace:

```
import _vue = require('vue');

declare global{
    const Vue: typeof _vue;
}
```

Don't forget to include this definition in tsconfig

Comment: It'd be pretty awesome to see a line-by-line explanation of what's going on in this snippet. TypeScript is sometimes hard to understand :)

Comment: Also with this snippet, TypeScript still gives a `Cannot find name 'Vue'` error for a line like `let test: Vue = new Vue({});`

Comment: @RomanNurik, first line imports Vues definition from `node_modules/vue/types/index.d.ts`, then `Vue` declared in global namespace. Have a look at this [global declaration template](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html). Regarding the error - it seems that _vue-global.d.ts_ is not included in your project.

Comment: Thanks! Oddly enough it works if I just do `let test = new Vue({});` ... Adding the type on the variable for some reason confuses the compiler.

Comment: Also for anyone who comes across this, I just discovered the `typeof` keyword here is used as a "type query": https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/31/type-queries-and-typeof-in-typescript

Comment: Adding `type Vue = _vue;` inside the declare global seemed to fix it. Also added `namespace Vue { type Component = _vue.Component; }` and others to get those available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [libs](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/types/) from official [documentation](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html).
Download all files.
In your typescript file add reference:

```
/// <reference path="../path_to../app/TypeScript/_definitely_typed/Vue/2.6.10/index.d.ts" />
```

Just change file **vue.d.ts**.

Comment line:

```
export const Vue: VueConstructor;
```

Add after:

```
declare global{
    const Vue: VueConstructor;
}
```